# I'm completely new to debugging PHP could someone explain what this means?

Tags: php, wordpress

As I said I'm new to PHP debugging, whilst my site works a wordpress plugin isn't behaving the way it should so I started to do PHP debugging.

I'm on Ubuntu and I've installed xdebugger and turned on debug in my wordpress config file.

My main problem is figuring out the output:

```
[18-Nov-2013 17:46:28 UTC] PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'lartMainFunctions' does not have a method 'lart_post_thumbnails' in /usr/share/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 406
[18-Nov-2013 17:46:28 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[18-Nov-2013 17:46:28 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/lart.co.uk/index.php:0
[18-Nov-2013 17:46:28 UTC] PHP   2. require() /var/www/lart.co.uk/index.php:17
[18-Nov-2013 17:46:28 UTC] PHP   3. require_once() /usr/share/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php:12
[18-Nov-2013 17:46:28 UTC] PHP   4. require_once() /usr/share/wordpress/wp-load.php:29
[18-Nov-2013 17:46:28 UTC] PHP   5. require_once() /etc/wordpress/wp-config.php:55
[18-Nov-2013 17:46:28 UTC] PHP   6. do_action() /usr/share/wordpress/wp-settings.php:296
[18-Nov-2013 17:46:28 UTC] PHP   7. call_user_func_array() /usr/share/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php:406
```

If somebody could me make more sense of these errors, that'd be great.

Comment: your code may have a bug :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually 1 error including the stacktrace, which tells you where the error is coming from start to end.

A valid callback is, when you give a function another function it should execute after finishing itself.

A class misses a method means, there is no

```
public function lart_post_thumbnails() { }
```

Within the class called in `/usr/share/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 406`

Maybe this is a typo and should be `last_post_thumbnails()` with an `s` instead of `r`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) but it's definitely supposed to say "lart". So there's a plugin that's calling my function and it's not executing?

Comment: It's not **existing** :-)

Comment: AHA! You are right!! I just found this `add_action('after_setup_theme', array(&$this,'lart_post_thumbnails'));` I forgot I deleted the function ages ago!